# How to plot a histogram with Plotly JS from pre-computed data

Tags: typescript, plot, nuxt.js, plotly.js

### Problem

For example, I have data like this, where `x` is `year` and `y` is `count`:

```json
{
  "x": [1950, 2000, 2010],
  "y": [1, 1, 5]
}
```

This means that the `count` is 1 between 1950-2000, also 1 between 2000-2010, and 5 between 2010-Now.

I want to make a histogram for this data. I feel that I'm very closed to the solution already, but somehow it still doesn't work.

### What I have tried

I create a bar chart and set `bargap` to 0. Additionally, the width of each bar is the difference in the year. For example, the width of the first bar is `2000 - 1950 = 50`. This is the function to calculate the bar width:

```js
calculateBarWidth (data: PlotData) {
  // The width of each bar is the difference between 2 consecutive years
  const diff: number[] = []

  for (let i = 1; i < data.x.length; i++) {
    diff.push(data.x[i] - data.x[i - 1])
  }

  // Last diff
  diff.push(10)

  return diff
}
```

I also know that by default, Plotly puts the `xtick` in the middle of the bar. So, for the first bar at 1950, it will look like this, where 1950 is at the red line:

[image: First bar]

Since this is a histogram, I want the year to be at the beginning of the bar, so I set the bar offset to half of its width.

Putting everything together, this is my plot function:

```js
createPlot (divElement: HTMLElement, data: PlotData) {
  const barWidth = this.calculateBarWidth(data)
  const barOffset = barWidth.map(value => value / 2)

  const plotData: any = [{
    x: data.x,
    y: data.y,
    type: 'bar',
    width: barWidth,
    offset: barOffset,
    hovertext: this.createHoverText(data),
    hoverinfo: 'text'
  }]

  const config = {
    responsive: false,
    displaylogo: false,
    displayModeBar: false
  }

  const layout = {
    title: {
      text: this.title,
      font: {
        size: 14
      }
    },
    xaxis: {
      title: {
        text: this.xlabel,
        font: {
          size: 14
        }
      },
      tickfont: {
        size: 12
      }
    },
    yaxis: {
      title: {
        text: this.ylabel,
        font: {
          size: 14
        }
      },
      tickfont: {
        size: 12
      }
    },
    bargap: 0,
    margin: {
      l: 50,
      r: 20,
      b: 40,
      t: 40
    }
  }

  Plotly.react(divElement, plotData, layout, config)
}
```

However, the plot looks like this:

[image: Plot with wrong offset]

Somehow, the first bar was offset so much that it overlaps with the other two, and the other two were not offset enough.

If I remove the offset completely, then the plot looks like this, which is completely wrong.

[image: Plot with no offset]

### Question

What did I do wrong? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I accidentally found the solution after trying out randomly.

It seems that the `xticks` are always in the middle of the bar because `offset = -barWidth / 2` is applied by default.

So, simply set the `offset` to `0` solves the problem.